# How can I set up a List to be loaded each time in C# Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a .txt file that i process into a List in my program.

I would like to somehow save that List and include it in the program itself so that it loads every time the program starts, so I don't have to process it every time from a .txt file.

Its more complicated than just "int x = 3;" cause it has like 10k lines and I don't wanna copy paste all that in the beginning.

I've looked all over but haven't found anything similar, any ideas guys?
Also if thee's a solution, can it work with any type (arrays, Dictionaries)?

As requested, the code is:

```
var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\jazz7\Desktop\links_zg.txt");
```

**EDIT**

Joe suggested the solution:
Included the file within the project, set its "build action" to embedded resource in Properties and used this code:

```
private string linkovi = "";
```

...

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); 
var resourceName = "WindowsFormsApplication4.links_zg.txt";
    using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
         linkovi = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

string linkovi now contains the txt file and is now within the application. Thanks all!

Comment: You are going to have to save it somewhere. If not hard coded then in a file or database. no way around that, I'm afraid.

Comment: Is the issue in the loading of the .txt file (eg speed issue) or is it something else?

Comment: Yes it is, the processing takes about 10 secs, i'd like to avoid that and have the LIst ready from the go since the file values never change.

Comment: Even processing 10k lines shouldn't take 10 seconds. Show us an excerpt of the file and the code your currently use to process it.

Comment: You are right, just came home to my laptop, tried it and it completed near-instantly. My apologies. 
But i would still want to include either the file or list within the .exe, because I will be moving it from PC to PC and would like everything in one file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the file as a resource in your executable file.

[This KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292) describes how to do it.

Comment: Alrighty, I've loaded the file, set it up as embedded resource, then wrote this: 
Assembly assembly = this.GetType().Assembly; using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication4.links2_zg.txt"));
 I've been searching for the past hour how to reference the txt file from the assembly. I've used:
var text = File.ReadAllText("WindowsFormsApplication4.links_zg.txt");

But i'm getting error "could not find file"

Comment: @RomanTušek - you shouldn't be using `File.ReadAllText` to read a resource stream.  You're on the right track with `GetManifestResourceStream`: if this returns null, you probably have the wrong resource name, otherwise you can then read text from the returned Stream using a `StreamReader`.  If it doesn't work, post code and a description of the problem you're having in an update to the question, or in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, youve got to choose between storing your data in memory or storing it on the hard drive. The former will cut your loading time, but might use an unacceptable amount of memory, whilst the latter is slower, as youve identified. Either way, your data has to be stored somewhere.

Do you need to load all of the data at once? If the loading time is the issue, you could process the file line by line. While this would be slower overall, you would still have access to some usable data sooner.

Comment: I'd like to store it in the memory, because I want to have the program mobile, to keep the file within itself. I don't want to  transport the file alongside the program. The txt file is 1.1 MB, so shouldn't be too critical :)

Comment: In that case, as @Joe mentions, you can store the file as a resource in your executable, and load it into memory as soon as your program starts. Youll take a hit when you first start up, but after that access should be reasonably quick.

Comment: Thank you @Richzilla for the reponse. I'm trying that now, but am stuck on the referencing the file to use it. See the comment at Joe's answer.